# Rails and ActiveRecord::Migration, edit migration to ignore table prefix or use explicit table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm retroactively writing ActiveRecord migrations inside a quirky, legacy Rails app that did not follow convention so well.

The models already exist, but were not made with a generator so the tables and everything in the past were set up by hand.

I'm changing that, and I made a migration to start (I'm also switching db behind the app from MS SQL Server to Postgres).

The migration looks like this:

```
class CreateSuite < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table :suites do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :owner
      t.string :resource_dependencies
      t.datetime :requested_time
      t.datetime :finished_time
      t.string :status
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

The application, which we'll say is called `foo` is set as an `active_record.table_name_prefix` in the `application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = 'foo_'
```

After the migration, I want a table that is named 'suites' but instead I get 'foo_suites'.  I do not want to change the prefix in `application.rb` since it's there for a reason (the application needs another table called 'foo_suites' but I'm going to tackle that with another migration file.)

How do I make this `ActiveRecord::Migration` create 'suites' instead of 'foo_suites'?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: no. I changed the prefix in `application.rb` :(

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to write it by hand with `connection.execute(%q{create table ... })`. This sort of cleanup/porting often requires getting your hands dirty.